# How to randomize Dart Flutter list items?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building a language application. The purpose of the application is to teach Turkish to the English. First, let me give you the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is a scrolling system. The Turkish language of the word written above the textFormField will be entered into the `textFormField`.

I keep the English word and its Turkish meaning in a list.

List:

```
  List<wordAndMeaning> wordsList = [
    wordAndMeaning("Hello", "Merhaba", false),
    wordAndMeaning("What's up?", "Naber", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How are you?", "Nasılsın", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Good morning", "Günaydın", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Good night", "İyi geceler", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's it going?", "Nasıl gidiyor", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day?", "Günün nasıldı", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day going?", "Günün nasıl gidiyor", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Nice to see you", "Seni görmek güzel", false),
    wordAndMeaning("It's been a while", "Görüşmeyeli uzun zaman oluyor", false),
  ];
```

The order in the screen scrolling system is exactly the same as in the list. I want it to be sorted randomly. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';

class selamlasma_test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<selamlasma_test1> createState() => _selamlasma_test1State();
}

class _selamlasma_test1State extends State<selamlasma_test1> {
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  List<wordAndMeaning> wordsList = [
    wordAndMeaning("Hello", "Merhaba", false),
    wordAndMeaning("What's up?", "Naber", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How are you?", "Nasılsın", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Good morning", "Günaydın", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Good night", "İyi geceler", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's it going?", "Nasıl gidiyor", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day?", "Günün nasıldı", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day going?", "Günün nasıl gidiyor", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Nice to see you", "Seni görmek güzel", false),
    wordAndMeaning("It's been a while", "Görüşmeyeli uzun zaman oluyor", false),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
        bottomOpacity: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text("Selamlaşma Testi 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 160;
        return Column(
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
              carouselController: _controller,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                reverse: false,
                height: height,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) => setState(() {
                  myController.clear();
                }),
              ),
              items: wordsList.map((wordAndMeaning word) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  word.word,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        width: 3
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          // border kalınlığı:
                                          width: 3,
                                          
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: '"' + word.word + '"' + " Türkçesi", floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, color: Colors.white),
                                      prefix: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 10),
                                        child: Icon(Icons.translate),
                                      ),
                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                    controller: myController,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  
                                ),
                                GFButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                  size: 45,
                                  text: "Kontrol et", textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                  // kenar ovallaştirme:
                                  shape: GFButtonShape.pills,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                     //eğer bir değer girilmemişse:
                                    if (myController.text == "") {
                                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                        content: Text("Lütfen bir değer giriniz!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                      ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    else if (myController.text.toLowerCase() != word.meaning.toLowerCase()) {
                                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                        content: Text("Yanlış cevap!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                      ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    if (myController.text.toLowerCase() == word.meaning.toLowerCase()) {
                                      print("Doğru");
                                      myController.clear();
                                      AlertDialog dogru = AlertDialog(
                                        content: Text("Tebrikler! Doğru bildiniz.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),),
                                        actions: [
                                          GFButton(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                            size: 35,
                                            text: "Sonraki soru", textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              _controller.nextPage(
                                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                                curve: Curves.ease,
                                              );
                                              // alert dialog u kapatma:
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        
                                        ],
                                      );

                                      showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                          return dogru;
                                        },
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),

            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          
                        ),
                        width: 55,
                        height: 55,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.previousPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                                
                            );
                          },
                          // köşeyi yuvarlaştırma:
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                          
                        )
                        
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        width: 55,
                        height: 55,
                        child: Container(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.nextPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                            );
                          },
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                          
                        )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }) ,
    );
  }
}

class wordAndMeaning {
  String word;
  String meaning;
  bool showMeaning;

  wordAndMeaning(this.word, this.meaning, this.showMeaning);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: wordsList.shuffle() can do. but if you have large data 100k slow.

Comment: int rnd = Random().nextInt(wordsList.length-1); and get index data wordsList[rnd]

Comment: @A.Sang In terms of runtime complexity, `List.shuffle` should be O(n), which is as fast as creating the `List` in the first place or creating a copy.  If that's a problem, the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm can be easily tweaked to amortize the runtime cost by shuffling elements one-by-one on demand.

Comment: 100000 List, shuffle Time-**147mills**. Random index Time **1<mills**

Comment: wordsList.shuffle(); **vs** print(wordsList[Random().nextInt(wordsList.length - 1)].word.toString());

Comment: @A.Sang 1. 147 ms is not very much. 2. You should be comparing is `wordsList.shuffle()` vs using `wordsList[random.nextInt(wordsList.length - 1)]` 100000 times.  The runtime cost should be about the same except that `wordsList.shuffle()` does all the work upfront.  Your approach would be faster overall if only a subset of elements is needed. 3. Your random selection is not quite the same since it can return duplicate elements. However, the OP didn't specify whether they wanted random with or without repeating elements, so that might be okay.)

Comment: i agree with you. i seen your image... it has one item from list. ya it has duplicate also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an initial state and use the `shuffle` method. Do the following.

```
 @override
  initState() {
     wordsList.shuffle();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will shuffle randomly your items :

```
 wordsList.shuffle();
```

Comment: Every time I scroll the page, the list is random again. I want the list to be mixed when this screen is opened. So I want it to be hash only once. Every time I swipe, the list gets shuffled again. I added the code inside the class `class _greeting_test1State extends State<greeting_test1> {` code.

Comment: I think you could mix shuffle() and remove()

Comment: @FredericChang Could you please send an example as an answer? I am a beginner in Dart Flutter.

Comment: don't put (wordsList.shuffle()) inside the build method so it won't call it every time when it rebuilds the widget tree

Comment: @MaJeed I get an error when I put it somewhere other than build. Where exactly should I put it?

Comment: before return Column(

Comment: @MaJeed It gives an `The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.dart(invalid_constructor_name)` error when you specify it right after the list.

Comment: @A.Sang I did what you said but it still happens in the order in the list.

Comment: @override
void initState() {
wordsList.shuffle();
    super.initState();

}

Comment: put in before @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)